# How to notice missing certificates in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, ssl-certificate

When I go to some sites, part of the site is missing. I don't have this problem in other browsers. After further experimentation I figured out that the reason is that the site uses different certificates for different parts of the site and I am missing some of them.

When I visit a site and the certificate is missing Firefox notifies me by stating that the certificate is not there. However when the certificate for the main file is fine it does not notify me about missing certificates for other parts of the site like pictures, etc. and just ignores those parts of the site. Is there a way to make Firefox also display notes for missing certificates for parts of the site?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your question is not regarding certificates but Mixed Content.

Open the page `about:config` and make sure those keys are configured this way:

```
security.mixed_content.block_active_content = false
security.mixed_content.block_display_content = false
```

If it was already fine, then I guess the easiest way out is to make a deep reset of your Firefox settings. Close Firefox, go to the folder `%APPDATA%\Mozilla` and delete the `Firefox` folder to restore Firefox to its installation defaults.